# Possible to upload to ftp server with URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering if there is a library that would enable me to upload a file to a remote server via ftp. I know there is ftplib, but from what i can tell, it only allows uploading from your own files. So if I had a URL like,  https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/d/db/Donald_Duck_Iconic.png , could I make a program to directly download/upload this to my ftp server. Instead of first having to download it to my own computer, then upload it to the server.

Sorry for formatting I'm on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use requests to download the file, and put the content into a BytesIO for upload:

```
from io import BytesIO
import requests

url = 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/d/db/Donald_Duck_Iconic.png'

response = requests.get(url)
f = BytesIO(response.content)
```

Then, `f` is a file-like object that is suitable for [FTP.storbinary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary).